# java mail API, how to split buffer to get URL

Tags: java

Hello i am stuck in my below mentioned code, the problem is, from buffer i am not able to get the url. My agenda is to get URL form a mail (user received a mail for registration and one URL is present in the mail to activate the account).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.search.SubjectTerm;

public class javamailtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javamailtest gmail = new javamailtest();
        gmail.read();
    }



    public void read() {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\smtp.properties")));
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "dummy@dummy.com","dummy_password");

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            int messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();

            System.out.println("Total Messages:- " + messageCount);

            /*
             * Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
             * System.out.println("------------------------------"); for (int i
             * = 0; i < 10; i++) { System.out.println("Mail Subject:- " +
             * messages[i].getSubject()); }
             */

            Message[] messages2;
            messages2 = inbox.search(new SubjectTerm("hello avinash test"),inbox.getMessages());

            System.out.println(messages2.length);
            for (int k = 0; k < messages2.length; k++) {
                System.out.println(messages2[k].getSubject());
                System.out.println(messages2[k].getContent().toString());
            }

            for (Message mail : messages2) {
                if (!mail.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {
                    // it's Working here
                    String line;
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    System.out.println("Buffer value:- "+buffer);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(mail.getInputStream()));
                    // this function is also working and returning 12 lines
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(line);
                    }
                    System.out.println("buffer content is" +buffer + buffer.length());

                    //System.out.println("Message Count is: "+ mail.getDescription());
                    // System.out.println("Message Count is: "+
                    // mail.getSubject());

                    try {
                        String eTest = buffer.toString().split("http://")[0];
                        /*System.out.println("String values are:- "+eTest);
                        int len = eTest.length();
                        System.out.println("String length is:- "+len);*/

                        /*if(buffer.toString().split("&amp;gt;http://148.251.25.56:8080/quantified/?")[0].split("href=")[1].length() <= 0){
                        String registrationURL = buffer.toString().split("&amp;gt;http://148.251.25.56:8080/quantified/?")[0].split("href=")[1];
                        int eTest = registrationURL.length();
                        System.out.println("length is:- "+eTest);
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                        System.out.println("Registration url value is:- "+registrationURL);
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("No url found");
                        }*/


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            }

            inbox.close(true);
            store.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

buffer content is

```
--089e01633ad4e78a0c04ff3e8e58Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable=E2=80=8Bhttp://148.251.25.56:8080/quantified/rewardsUser.action‌​--089e01633ad4e78a0c04ff3e8e58Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable<div dir=3D"ltr"><div class=3D"gmail_default" style=3D"font-family:arial,he=lvetica,sans-serif">=E2=80=8B<a href=3D"148.251.25.56:8080/quantifie=d/… –
```

Comment: buffer content is--089e01633ad4e78a0c04ff3e8e58Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable=E2=80=8Bhttp://148.251.25.56:8080/quantified/rewardsUser.action--089e01633ad4e78a0c04ff3e8e58Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable<div dir=3D"ltr"><div class=3D"gmail_default" style=3D"font-family:arial,he=lvetica,sans-serif">=E2=80=8B<a href=3D"http://148.251.25.56:8080/quantifie=d/rewardsUser.action">http://148.251.25.56:8080/quantified/rewardsUser.acti=on</a></div></div>--089e01633ad4e78a0c04ff3e8e58

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with JavaMail specifically, it's just a data parsing problem.

Comment: Ya you are  right i am stuck with the parsing. Can you please help me to parse for URL?

Comment: Regular Expression can help you to parse the URL . I can see two URLS here 1) http://148.251.25.56:8080/quantified/rewardsUser.action?? and 2) a href=3D"148.251.25.56:8080/quantifie=d/…     Which One you need to Use ?

Comment: 148.251.25.56:8080/quantified/rewardsUser.action??  this one i want to get.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't understand the structure of mail messages.  You might want to start with this [JavaMail FAQ entry to find the main text content of your message](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody).  Once you have the text content, it is, as others have said, just a string parsing problem.